# How to pass data between two functional components in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

I am trying to pass data between two **functional components** but getting `undefined` value.

**File1.js** //functional Component 1

```
const file1 = ({navigation}) => {
      navigation.navigate('file2',{data:"Hello"});
};
```

**File2.js** //functional Component 2

```
const file2 = ({navigation}) => {
  console.log(navigation.getParam("data");
};
```

Comment: What is the log of navigation.state.params or navigation.state in general?

Comment: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: I cannot track your issue but its clear you are not sending any params with navigation.

Answer (score 2):

My Solution

**File1.js** //functional Component 1

```
const file1 = ({navigation}) => {
      navigation.navigate('file2',{item :"Hello"});
};
```

**File2.js** //functional Component 2

```
const file2 = (props) => {
  console.log(props.route.params.item);
};
```